# Getting Error: The package '@react-native-community/geolocation' doesn't seem to be linked. in React Native CLI

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I am trying to

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
```

in my react native app

I have done yarn add @react-native-community/geolocation

but I keep getting the module is not linked error.
I have tried restarting the app and added permission in AndroidManifest.Xml but that doesn't help either

I am using  "react-native": "0.70.5"
and I am currently using android
Please help, how do I fix this

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolve this?? O am getting the same error on Android. Works fine on IOS

Comment: Hi, I just did yarn build android again and restarted my app and it got automatically linked